# Static path URL is not getting priority over RequestMapping Url

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

My application is hosted on https://somedomain.com/app-name
I have defined RequestMapping as `"/app-name/**"` as user can hit:

```
 https://somedomain.com/app-name
 https://somedomain.com/app-name/some-url
 https://somedomain.com/app-name/some-other-url
 https://somedomain.com/app-name/some-url/some-sub-url
```

So I need the rest of the path (which can contain / also)
RequestMapping as /app-name/** is solving my problem but then my static content doesn't get served as static-path-pattern: /app-name/static/**

Why Request mapping is getting priority over static-path-pattern? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If possible in your application, Try changing static-path-pattern `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Comment: I have a limitation that my application can be hosted on  https://somedomain.com/app-name so I have to mention /app-name in the static-path-pattern value